# Python: JSON - string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

**input JSON file format.**

```
{
    "Orange_2001": {
        "dir": "/home/fruits/orange.check",
        "path": "/home/fruits/orange",
        "name": "Orange"
    },
    "Apple_345": {
        "dir": "/home/fruits/apple.check",
        "path": "/home/fruits/apple",
        "name": "Apple"
    }
}
```

Im trying to convert it to below format, but facing `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

```
{
    "Orange": { "/home/fruits/orange.check": "/home/fruits/orange" },

    "Apple": { "/home/fruits/apple.check": "/home/fruits/apple" }
}
```

Code snippet :

```
fruits = {}
    with open('fruits.json', 'r') as data:
        metadata = json.load(data)
        for key, value in metadata.items():
            fruits[metadata[key]['name']] = {}
            fruits[metadata[key]['name']] = metadata[key]['name']['dir']
            fruits[metadata[key]['name']] = metadata[key]['name']['path']
```

Am I missing something silly ?

Comment: Probably you do. Do some debugging to find out what.

Comment: I tried my best, unfortunately, unable to figure that out.

Comment: What are the values of `metadata`, `metadata[key]`, `metadata[key]['name']`, each? One of them is actually a string but you expect a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a typo:

`metadata[key]['name']['dir']`

Should be:

`metadata[key]['dir']`

(and the same for the line below)

Also you can replace `metadata[key]` with `value` everywhere, that's the point of iterating with .items() !

Additionally, your code wouldn't produce the desired output right now, as you would get : `{"Orange" : "home/fruits/orange", "Apple" : "home/fruits/apple"}`. You should replace the three lines in your for loop by:

`fruits[value['name']] = {value['dir']: value['path']}`

Comment: I don think your advise fixes the problem

Comment: It certainly fixed the "TypeError" that he was asking about (as he was trying to index a string with another string), but it's true that the output would still not have been correct. I edited my response to be more complete.

Comment: @AdrienFoucart : thats silly of me, thanks much !!